# Solve $e^x\sin y = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

How do I solve for $x$ and $y$ in $e^x\sin y = 2$

If $e^x = 2$ and $\sin y = 1$, I get $x = \ln2$ and $y = (4n-3)\frac{\pi}{2}$

But are these the only $x$? I don't think so.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have another equation?

Comment: Do you require $x$ and $y$ to be real?

Comment: Since this is tagged complex-analysis, it seems relevant to note that if $x$ and $y$ are real, the LHS of the equation is the imaginary part of $e^{x+iy}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want other real solutions, note that $e^x >0$ and $-1 \le \sin(y)\le 1$

so if their product is $2$ then you need $0 < \sin(y) \le 1$, i.e.

- any $y$ with $2n\pi < y \lt (2n+1)\pi$ for some $n$,
- giving
  $x = \log_e\left(\frac{2}{\sin(y)}\right)$ which will be $\ge \log_e(2)$

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ge\ln(2)$, $e^x\ge 2$, so any $y$ where $0\le\sin(y)\le 1$ is possible.  For a single range $0\le y\le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$2 = e^x\sin y = \Im(e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)) = \Im(e^{x+iy}) = \Im(e^z)$ where $z = x + iy$. Therefore, all $z=x+iy$ such that $\Im(e^z) = 2$ is solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since one equation only is available when two are needed to solve fully.. we have intersections of a contour with a plane as $f(x,y)$ in the real.

[image]

In this case oscillatory sin function produces two intersections as seen in the 3d plot.